# how to get from Grodno to Bahatyrevičy with public transport

Tags: public-transport, belarus

Is it possible to get from [Grodno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grodno) to [Bahatyrevičy](https://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%87%D1%8B) (also known as Багатырэвічы, Богатыревичи, Bohatyrowicze) with public transport? I am willing to go a few kilometers by foot, so, for instance, getting from Grodno to [Глядавічы](https://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%87%D1%8B_(%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%9E%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%96_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%91%D0%BD)) and then going 5 km by foot is also ok for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this timetable of buses](http://ticketbus.by/) it is possible. You have to go by bus from Grodno to Грушевка (in Belarussian: Грушаўка, Hrušaŭka) and then go about 8 km [by foot to Bohatyrowicze](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Grushevka+%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0/Bogatyrevichi,+Belarus/@53.4837491,24.0965795,14z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x46dfc6c80300e165:0x8575f0f0c05615e7!2m2!1d24.1303283!2d53.4786238!1m5!1m1!1s0x46dfc65def821d71:0xe8f5e6f4e5072615!2m2!1d24.1607173!2d53.5123113!3e2). When you look up the bus at the timetable be careful, because there are at least two places called Грушевка - the one you need is "Грушевка, Гродненский р-н ГРОДНЕНСКАЯ ОБЛ. Беларусь". The bus which you need is a bus from Grodno to Мосты through Грушевка. Notice that the hours of this bus are different for different days.

It is also possible - but more complicated - to go by train from Grodno to Мосты (train's timetable is [here](https://rasp.rw.by/)) and then take a bus from Мосты to Grodno through Грушевка, and again - go by foot from Грушевка to Bohatyrowicze.